# How to get distinct data along with the code of first distinct data encountered

Tags: sql

```
+----------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| Coloumn1 | Coloumn2 |       Coloumn3        |          coloumn4           |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| NULL     | AAAA     | NOTICE                | Plaintiffs Notice of Filing |
| NULL     | AAAB     | NOTICE CANCEL HEARING | Plaintiffs Notice of Filing |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I have this table and I want to get distinct value from `coloumn4`.

I also need the `Coloumn2` data for the first corresponding column 4 data. For example, row 1 and 2 have same data in `coloumn4`. So on applying query I need data like:

```
Coloumn2 | Coloumn4
---------|----------------------------
AAAA     | Plaintiffs Notice of Filing
```

What is the SQL query to get this data?

Comment: What have you tried that doesn't work? And what does "first" mean - smallest value of Column2, or something else?

Comment: i have 191 records in this table. Have 75 distinct records in coloumn4 and 191 distinct coloumn2 . On applying distinct on coloumn4 i get 75 records and on applying distinct on combination of coloumn2 and 4 i get 191 records. So need only 75 records with their column 2 data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT column4, MIN(column2)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY column4
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7918/1)